# Xamarin Forms image mismatch between Android and iOS

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin Forms project, for iOS only one pdf format figure is present, android any resolution of figure in each resource folder.

But Android images are showed bigger than iOS ones.

For example, using a button:

```
<Button  Text=""
         Image="btnmail"
         WidthRequest="60"
         HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
  />
```

On iOS, result is:

[image]

On android, instead:

[image]

Any idea about why that happens?

Answer (score 1):

You should prepare all size of icon for different Android device because they have different screen resolution.

[image]

> lpdi ⇒ 300 px * 180 px
>
> mdpi ⇒ 400 px * 240 px
>
> hdpi ⇒ 600 px * 360 px
>
> xhdpi ⇒ 800 px * 480 px
>
> xxhdpi ⇒ 1200 px * 720 px
>
> xxxhdpi ⇒ 1600 px * 960 px

And you can refer to [this document.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio).